# spriteKit collision not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Not sure which part is the problem. I'm doing a spriteKit shooter game and the collision isn't working. The spaceships are not being destroyed.

It must have to do with the collision somewhere...

The projectiles are just moving the enemy over slightly but not destroying them.

```
    struct physicsCategory {
        static let player : UInt32 = 1
         static let enemy : UInt32 = 2
        static let projectile : UInt32 = 3


    }


        func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
            let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

            if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.projectile) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.projectile)) {


                projectileCollision(enemyTemp: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, projectileTemp: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

            }
            if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.player) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy)) {


                enemyPlayerCollision(enemyTemp: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, playerTemp: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

            }
        }
        ///////////
        func projectileCollision(enemyTemp: SKSpriteNode, projectileTemp: SKSpriteNode){
            enemy.removeFromParent()
            projectile.removeFromParent()

            score = score + 1

            updateScore()




        }


    ////////////
        func enemyPlayerCollision(enemyTemp: SKSpriteNode, playerTemp: SKSpriteNode) {

            mainLabel.fontSize = 50
            mainLabel.alpha = 1.0
            mainLabel.text = "Game Over"

            player.removeFromParent()

            isAlive = false

            waitThenMoveToTiltleScreen()
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code where you set up the physicBodies and collisionBitMasks for your sprites, as well? your `PhysicsCategory` struct seems to indicate that you are not entirely comfortable with how bitMasks work...

Comment: func spawnProjectile(){
         projectile = SKSpriteNode(color: offWhiteColor, size: projectileSize)
        projectile.size = projectileSize
        projectile.position = CGPoint(x: (player.position.x), y: (player.position.y))
     projectile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: projectile.size)
         projectile.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.projectile
        projectile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.enemy
        projectile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

Comment: Hi T.Benjamin sorry I could only paste in this small  amount of code . but I have put an answer/question in below . just some of the projectiles are passing through the enemies but not all .I guess its what knightOf Dragon was talking abou "need to handle the condition where your first body is projectile, and your second body is enemy" but I can't seem to do it as I'm fairly new at spriteKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is `static let projectile : UInt32 = 3`

If you want to declare a unique bitMasks, it needs to be in a power of 2 (2^0,2^1,2^2,..etc)

What 3 really means, is your projectile is both a player and an enemy ( 1 = 2^0, 2 = 2^1)

Your second issue is your logic

```
let f = firstBody.categoryBitMask
let s = secondbody.categoryBitmask
let p = physicsCategory.projectile
let x = physicsCategory.player
let e = physicsCategory.enemy
```

This is your projectile if statements:

```
if ((f == p) && (s == e) || (f == e) && (s == p)) {
   projectileCollision(enemyTemp: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, projectileTemp: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
}
```

In your if statement, you are saying either first or second could be the enemy, but in your projectile collision method, you are claiming that first body is always the enemy, and second body is always the projectile.

You need to handle the condition where your first body is projectile, and your second body is enemy, because chances are, your projectile will move into enemy, so it would be the first body.

Comment: thank you . whats the best way  to handle the condition where your first body is projectile, and your second body is enemy..

Comment: At the moment the player is the only one that gets removed FromParent.Even though I've put enemy.removeFromParent()
        projectile.removeFromParent() underneath in the same statement..

Comment: you need to guarantee your enemy is first body somehow and your missle is second body,  use new variable and do a check for who is first or second, and assign it to the new variable

Answer (score 0):

thanks ( sorry I'm fairly new to spriteKit) I'm nearly there I think as I've written this code below and it worked better.

just with one small problem! some of the projectiles just go through the enemys.and only some destroy.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.projectile) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.projectile) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy)) {


            projectileCollision(enemy: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, projectile: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

            }
        else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.player) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.enemy)) {


            enemyPlayerCollision(enemy: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, person: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

        }
    }
    ///////////
    func projectileCollision(enemy: SKSpriteNode, projectile: SKSpriteNode){

        enemy.removeFromParent()
        projectile.removeFromParent()

        score = score + 1

        updateScore()


    }



    ////////////
    func enemyPlayerCollision(enemy: SKSpriteNode, person: SKSpriteNode) {

        mainLabel.fontSize = 50
        mainLabel.alpha = 1.0
        mainLabel.text = "Game Over"

        person.removeFromParent()
      enemy.removeFromParent()

        isAlive = false

        waitThenMoveToTiltleScreen()
    }
```

Comment: ok getting somewhere now . The projectiles were to fast so the collision was not detecting all of the collisions only some !